# What is the correct way to cast an image handle to coherent uimage2D

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader

I have an image handle, that I'm trying to cast to a coherent uimage2D with layout r32ui. My problem is that this cast works on nvidia:

```
const layout(r32ui) coherent uimage2D id_texture_t = layout(r32ui) uimage2D(id_texture[matrixIndex]);
```

This cast works on some amd:

```
const layout(r32ui) coherent uimage2D id_texture_t = uimage2D(id_texture[matrixIndex]);
```

But on some other amd neither of these work, if I try to use the second one I get:

```
ERROR: 0:223: error(#167) Only allowed at global scope: coherent
ERROR: 0:223: error(#200) Qualifier combination "const" and "coherent" not allowed
ERROR: 0:223: error(#386) Layout qualifier "qualifier" does not apply to "const"
```

Is there anything that could work on this card? It's radeon rx 460 with latest drivers.

Comment: Does the variable have to be `const`-qualified? Did you initialize the extension properly?

Comment: It does not need to be const, just coherent. I have enabled the bindless texture extension and it is supported.